# Detecting that I am connected to a vpn/wifi and if not I automatically reconnect

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

so I made a script that logs into my schools vpn automatically by entering my username and password for me in my raspberry pi.  Now I am trying to see if there is a way I can have a script running in the background that detects that I am connected to my vpn and also to my local wifi.  If it detects there is no connection, then it will run my script of logging into the vpn automatically.
Below is the script I use to login to my vpn automatically my login.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo openconnect vpn.ucr.edu/engineering 
expect -r "\[sudo] .*\: " {
       send "pw_for_my_linux\n"
}

expect "Username:" {
       send "my_vpn_username\n"
}

expect "Password:" {
       send "vpn_password\n"
}
interact
```

Comment: `openconnect` has a reconnect feature https://askubuntu.com/questions/803021/how-to-automatically-connect-openconnect-vpn-when-the-connection-closes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use ethtool and check the connection status by looking at network interfaces.

```
ifconfig
```

(view network interface names, select network interface known to be associated with working vpn)

```
sudo ethtool eth0
```

Where 'eth0' is replaced by the name of the network interface that your vpn software is using

OUTPUT should look something like this if it's communicating (replace example net interface name eth0 with relevant one you can see in ifconfig):

> Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
>
> drv probe link    Link detected: yes

OUTPUT if down?:

> Settings for eth0:
>
> Link detected: no

In your bash code you can poll the 'link detected' status, parse out the answer to determine if you try reconnecting. Warning, haven't been able to test this on a vpn connection -- I have to use a special client other than openconnect, and for me I know the VPN is down if I run

```
ifconfig | grep "tun0"
```

If that returns something, VPN is up. If my network interface called tun0 is missing, VPN is not up.

Hope this gets you moving in the right direction!